# How to open a AlertDialog in a full width of screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I want the Dialog like below. [image: this]. So I have opened activity as AlertDialog as well as used custom alert dialog also. Code for Custom AlertDialog is given below

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_user_dialoge, null);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            builder.setView(dialogLayout);

            AlertDialog customAlertDialog = builder.create();

    WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = customAlertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();

    wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.START;
    wmlp.y = 120;//y position
    customAlertDialog.show();

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    int displayWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
     int dialogWindowWidth = (int) (displayWidth *2);
    wmlp.width = dialogWindowWidth;

            customAlertDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(wmlp);
```

But its giving answer like below.[image: this]. How to remove that marked left space?

Comment: Have you tried setting the width of the layout as "match_parent" and remove if any padding or margin is set to the layout.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways this can be done, first one in style.xml and second in code:

1. Add as below in style.xml, alter the value(currently 90%) to meet your needs.

> ```
> <style name="Theme_Dialog" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
>     <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">90%</item>
>     <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">90%</item>
> </style>
> ```

2. Add setlayout to match_parent

> ```
>  final Dialog contacts_dialog = new Dialog(ActivityGroup.this,
>  R.style.theme_sms_receive_dialog);
>  contacts_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_schedule_date_time);
> ```

```
getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

 contacts_dialog.setCancelable(true);
 contacts_dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
 contacts_dialog.show();
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, we have implemented this solution, but its not working for me.